# Fluent Command Line Parser Call Function

Tags: c#, parsing, command-line-interface

I'm using FluentCommandLineParser to handle parsing of my Command Line utility.
I would like to set it up so that different command, take different parameters.

I've set up a single parser like so:

```
public class RoslynCliOptions
{
    public string SolutionFile { get; set; }
}

public static FluentCommandLineParser<RoslynCliOptions> GetRoslynCliOptionParser()
{
    var parser = new FluentCommandLineParser<RoslynCliOptions>();

    parser.Setup(x => x.SolutionFile).As('s', "SolutionPath");
    return parser;
}
```

Now All of this makes sense if I were just to pass options to a command line I could do from my shell

```
MyExecutable -s="C://SolutionPath.Sln"
```

How do I configure the Command line parser to parse a command with this as well.

So I can call

```
MyExecutable GenerateClass --name="foo"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands still in pre-release however you can download [via nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentCommandLineParser/1.5.0.7-commands) or get the assemblies from the latest build on [teamcity.jetbrains.com](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=FluentCommandLineParser_15preRelease&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts)

Example below and also [see here](https://github.com/fclp/fluent-command-line-parser/blob/commands/FluentCommandLineParser.Examples/Program.cs#L25).

```
myapp.exe add "c:\file1.txt" "c:\file2.txt" --verbose --ignore-errors
myapp.exe rem "c:\file1.txt" "c:\file2.txt" --verbose
```

We have two commands here, Add and Remove, both can have different options and rules.

```cs
// Contains all arguments for the add command
class AddArgs {
 bool Verbose;
 bool IgnoreErrors;
 IEnumerable<string> Files;
}

// Contains all arguments for the remove command
class RemoveArgs {
 bool Verbose;
 IEnumerable<string> Files;
}

// entry point into console app
static void Main(string[] args) {
 var fclp = new FluentCommandLineParser();

 // use new SetupCommand method to initialise a command
 var addCmd = fclp.SetupCommand<AddArgs>("add")
                  .Callback(args => Add(args)); // executed when the add command is used

 // the standard fclp framework, except against the created command rather than the fclp itself
 addCmd.Setup(args => args.Verbose)
       .As('v', "verbose")
       .SetDefault(false)
       .WithDescription("Be verbose");

 addCmd.Setup(args => args.IgnoreErrors)
       .As("ignore-errors")
       .SetDefault(false)
       .WithDescription("If some files could not be added, do not abort");

 addCmd.Setup(args => args.Files)
       .As('f', "files")
       .Description("Files to be tracked")
       .UseForOrphanArguments();

 // add the remove command
 var removeCmd = fclp.SetupCommand<RemoveArgs>("rem")
                     .Callback(args => Remove(args)); // executed when the remove command is used

 removeCmd.Setup(args => args.Verbose)
          .As('v', "verbose")
          .SetDefault(false)
          .WithDescription("Be verbose");

 removeCmd.Setup(args => args.Files)
          .As('f', "files")
          .WithDescription("Files to be untracked")
          .UseForOrphanArguments();

 fclp.Parse(args);
}

void Add(AddArgs args){
  // add was executed
}

void Remove(RemoveArgs args){
  // remove was executed
}
```

Comment: Props for reviving this old thread, definetly will be useful in the future

Comment: unfortunately this feature even in the latest pre-release version `1.5.0.20-commands` is hardly usable: `parser.HelpOption.ShowHelp(parser.Options)` prints `No options have been setup` (which is reasonable - only commands are at the top level), but `parser.HelpOption.ShowHelp(parser.Commands)` isn't supported; enums as command options aren't handled properly...